# Django site using mod_wsgi on AWS cannot create FK form field because related model has not been loaded yet

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, mod-wsgi

I'm working on a Django site, using the Django 1.4 official release. My site has a few apps. One of the apps has a model named `Campaign` with FKs to models in the other apps. As suggested in the Django reference (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey), I chose to define the FK fields using a string instead of the related model classes themselves since I expect to have circular references in the next version or so, and this approach avoids circular import issues.

When I deployed the site on AWS (Amazon Web Services) using the BitNami djangostack 1.4 (Apache, mod_wsgi, MySQL), my deployed site worked correctly for the most part. On pages displaying forms for the `Campaign` model, Django raised an exception when trying to create a form field relying on a foreign key field of the `Campaign` model, complaining the related model was not loaded. The funny/scary thing is that when I set `settings.DEBUG` to True (definitely not something we'll want once the site goes live), the issue no longer occurs!

The site worked perfectly when I tested it on my local Django development server, and it also worked perfectly using the same BitNami djangostack deployed on my Windows workstation.

Here's the relevant Apache error output I see on the AWS console.

```
[error] ERROR :: Internal Server Error: /campaigns/
[error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[error]   File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 101, in get_response
[error]     request.path_info)
    ... (django/wsgi blah blah)
[error]   File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project/campaign/views.py", line 5, in <module>
[error]     from forms import CampaignForm
[error]   File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project/campaign/forms.py", line 12, in <module>
[error]     class CampaignForm(forms.ModelForm):
[error]   File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 206, in __new__
[error]     opts.exclude, opts.widgets, formfield_callback)
[error]   File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 160, in fields_for_model
[error]     formfield = f.formfield(**kwargs)
[error]   File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1002, in formfield
[error]     (self.name, self.rel.to))
[error] ValueError: Cannot create form field for 'reward' yet, because its related model 'reward.Reward' has not been loaded yet
```

So, here's a quick recap:

1. My site works on my local Django development server, regardless of settings.DEBUG value
2. With the BitNami stack on my local Windows machine, it works, regardless of settings.DEBUG value
3. With the BitNami stack on AWS (Ubuntu), it works with DEBUG = True *but not with DEBUG = False*

I understand *what* the error means, but I don't understand *why* it's occurring, i.e. why the dependent model is not loaded. Has anyone ever encountered a similar issue, or has advice that could help me fix it?

Note: I tried to Google the error message but all I found was the Django source code where that error was raised. I also tried searching for more general queries like `mod_wsgi django related model`, but I couldn't find anything that seemed relevant to my problem.

Comment: Is the related model's app included in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes, all the apps of my site are in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Does order of the apps matter?

Comment: One of the links I found while googling is http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html. I'm not sure it can help me or not, but I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @mbargiel that link saved me! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, I found a solution to my problem on a blog post by Graham Dumpleton (http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html).

In short, the Django development server validates the models (which resolves string-based relations) when starting, and that operation probably wasn't done when using mod_wsgi under the BitNami djangostack on Ubuntu with DEBUG = False. Very specific conditions, I know - but G. Dumpleton's 'fixed' mod_wsgi code solved the issue for me.

This is what my wsgi.py looks like now:

```
#wsgi.py

#make sure the folder containing the apps and the site is at the front of sys.path
#maybe we could just define WSGIPythonPath in django.conf file...?
project_root = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))) 
if project_root not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, project_root)

#set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable (doesn't work without this, despite what G. Dumpleton's blog post said)
site_name = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(__file__))
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "%s.settings" % site_name)

#new code - fixes inter-app model dependencies
from my_site import settings
import django.core.management
django.core.management.setup_environ(settings)  # mimic manage.py
utility = django.core.management.ManagementUtility()
command = utility.fetch_command('runserver')
command.validate()  # validate the models - *THIS* is what was missing

#setup WSGI application object
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same problem, however in my case it happens when I have DEBUG set to True. And wsgi.py of yours is not working on my instance. [Here is](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L1009) a line in django code that rises an exception.

Comment: This solution works for Heroku too if people are having trouble deploying on that and are incurring the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I had just this problem and was looking at modifying wsgi.py as suggested. Then a colleague suggested simply reordering the apps in INSTALLED_APPS and, hey presto, it's working without having to touch the wsgi.py.

Comment: It would be great if you could you indicate how you re-ordered them to fix the problem, i.e. moving which app where solved it. I'm sure it could help other people facing the same kind of problem.

Comment: So, the error was 'Cannot create form field for 'xyz' yet, because its related model 'abc' has not been loaded yet'. I just moved the app that contained abc to before the app that contained xyz.

Comment: I think your problem was different than mine (though the symptom was similar). My problem was that under a certain environment, it worked only when settings.DEBUG was set to True so obviously, it was not an app ordering issue. In the end, I found that the wsgi wrapper did not always validate the models (depending on DEBUG) on launch, so attempting to import a model that depended on a model from a different app failed because my app models had not been parsed at all (regardless of the INSTALLED_APPS order). That's why my fix was to add the model validation explicitly in my wsgi.py.